# Error on click event on a map marker with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, maps

I use Leaflet (1.7.1) to add markers on a plan, corresponding to search results.
Onclick on a marker, I want to select the corresponding result on the list.

For each result, I add a marker like this :
`var marker = L.marker([{{ result.adresse.lat }}, {{ result.adresse.lng }}]).addTo(mymap);`

This works well.

Just after this code, I add `marker.on("click", console.log("toto"))`
but onclik on this marker, I have this error :

```
Events.js:190 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at i.fire (Events.js:190)
    at i._fireDOMEvent (Map.js:1440)
    at i._handleDOMEvent (Map.js:1397)
    at HTMLDivElement.c (DomEvent.js:92)
```

The weird thing is that this function is called (I do have 'toto' displayed on my console) when the page loads...

Any clue to identify the pb ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the problem.

I tried to call the click function like that : `marker.on('click', myfunction())` and below define `myfunction()`

But this must be defined like that :
`marker.on('click', function(e){myfunction()});`
And like that, it works.

Comment: Or `marker.on('click', myfunction)` (no parenthesis after the function name, so that you pass a reference to that function, instead of executing it directly)